# Generar un número aleatorio en java dentro de diferentes rangos en java

Tags: java, random

Quisiera saber como generar un numero aleatorio dentro de un intervalo de valores dentro del cual también habrá intervalos de números no válidos. Por ejemplo me gustaría generar un número aleatorio del 1 al 100 pero no me valen los número del 50 al 60. O lo que es lo mismo, pasarle varios rangos de valores (del 1 al 49 y del 61 al 100)

Sé que podría hacer con `int numero = (int) (Math.random() * n) + 1;` y volviendo a ejecutar la instrucción si sale un número no válido pero quiero saber si existe algun método para hacerlo directamente.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de hacerlo es utilizando un bucle while y generando un número aleatorio dentro del intervalo deseado. Si el número generado está dentro de los intervalos no deseados, se generará otro número hasta que se obtenga uno que esté dentro del intervalo deseado.

Ejemplo:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 100;
        int[][] excludeRanges = {{50, 60}}; // Rangos que no deseamos
        int number;

        do {
            number = new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        } while (!isValid(number, excludeRanges));

        System.out.println(number);
    }

    private static boolean isValid(int number, int[][] excludeRanges) {
        for (int[] range : excludeRanges) {
            int min = range[0];
            int max = range[1];
            if (number >= min && number <= max) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo, `min` y `max` son los valores mínimo y máximo del intervalo deseado. `excludeRanges` es un arreglo bidimensional que contiene los rangos que no deseamos. En el método `isValid()`, comprobamos si el número generado está dentro de alguno de los rangos no deseados. Si es así, se devuelve `false`, de lo contrario se devuelve `true`. En el bucle `do-while`, generamos un número aleatorio dentro del intervalo deseado y comprobamos si es válido utilizando el método `isValid()`. Si no es válido, generamos otro número aleatorio hasta que se obtenga uno que sea válido. Finalmente, imprimimos el número generado.

Comment: La fuera bruta es una opción. Pero podrías tener la mala suerte de que no cumpla las condiciones durante varios ciclos seguidos. Es mejor plantearlo inteligentemente.

Answer (score 0):

La forma para evitar bucles podría seria seleccionar dentro de los posibles rangos uno de forma aleatoria y dentro de el rango seleccionado generar un numero aleatorio.

De esta forma te quitas de tener que ejecutar varias veces la obtención del numero aleatorio haciendo el codigo mucho mas optimo.

```java
public class Random {

  private static final SecureRandom RANDOM = new SecureRandom();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<Range> validRanges = Arrays.asList(new Range(1, 49), new Range(61, 100));
    final int randomNumber = randomNumberByRanges(validRanges);
    System.out.println(randomNumber);
  }

  private static int randomNumberByRanges(final List<Range> ranges) {
    final int rangeSelectedIndex = RANDOM.nextInt(0, ranges.size());
    final Range rangeSelected = ranges.get(rangeSelectedIndex);
    return rangeSelected.randomNumber();
  }

  private static final class Range {

    private final int min;

    private final int max;

    private Range(final int min, final int max) {
      this.min = min;
      this.max = max;
    }

    private int randomNumber() {
      // Se suma 1 al maximo porque el metodo nextInt no incluye el maximo.
      return RANDOM.nextInt(this.min, this.max + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dado que el método ***random** nos devuelve un valor entre "0" (incluido)  y "1" (no incluido), no se puede hacer lo que pides en un solo paso, creo que generar dos números aleatorios, es la solución más cercana a lo que pides...

```
int aleatorioConIntervalo( int piso, int techo, int intervalo[] ) {
   int numero = (int) ( Math.random() * techo ) + piso;
   int numeroAux = 0;
   if( numero > intervalo[ 0 ] && numero < intervalo[ 1 ] ) {
      if( numero % 2 == 0 ) {
         numeroAux = (int) ( Math.random() * ( intervalo[ 0 ] - piso )) + numero - intervalo[ 0 ];
         numero -= numeroAux;
      }
      else {
         numeroAux = (int) ( Math.random() * ( techo - intervalo[ 1 ] )) + intervalo[ 1 ] - numero;
         numero += numeroAux;
      }
   }
   return numero;
}
```

Como se puede ver, se genera un primer aleatorio, que si no se encuentra entre los valores prohibidos, se devuelve.
Lo que sucede cuando está en la zona roja, lo voy a explicar con el siguiente ejemplo:

rango 1 -> 100
prohibido 50 -> 60

numero generado -> 52

se genera aux con valor entre 0 y 49 (intervalo[ 0 ] - piso)
se le suma 2 (numero - intervalo[ 0 ])

se decrementa numero con el valor de aux

numero generado -> 57

se genera aux con valor entre 0 y 40 (techo - intervalo[ 1 ])
se le suma 3 (intervalo[ 1 ] - numero)

se aumenta numero con el valor de aux

Espero que sea de utilidad.